# awk the column of one file from another file

Tags: awk

having some trouble with awk. I have two files and am trying to read a column of the 2nd file with the first and pull out all matches.

file1:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5
```

file2:

```
apples  peaches 3  
apples  peaches 9  
oranges  pears 7  
apricots  figs 1
```

expected output:

```
apples peaches 3  
apricots figs 1
```

```sh
awk -F"|" '
           FNR==NR {f1[$1];next}
           ($3 in f1)
          ' file1 file2 > output.txt
```

Comment: Why do you have `-F"|"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear (to me) the format of `file2` (eg, is that a space or tab between fields?), or if a line in `file2` could have more than 3 (white) spaced delimited strings (eg, `apples black raspberries 6`), so picking a delimiter for `file2` would require more details.  Having said that ...

- there are no pipes ('|') in the sample files so the current code (using `-F"|"`) is going to lump the entire line into `awk` variable `$1`
- we can make this a bit easier by recognizing that we're only interested in the **last** field from `file2`

Adding an entry to `file2`:

```
$ cat file2
apples  peaches 3
apples  peaches 9
oranges  pears 7
apricots  figs 1
apples black raspberries 2
```

A couple small changes to the current `awk` code:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {f1[$1]; next} $(NF) in f1' file1 file2
```

This generates:

```
apples  peaches 3
apricots  figs 1
apples black raspberries 2
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The delimiter here is white space, sorry for not making that clear. Just for reference, if there was data following our column of interest and it wasnt the final column, what would that look like/how would this change?

Comment: that would depend how many columns come afterwards, the column delimiter, and whether or not the follow-on column(s) contain the delimiter; net result: it depends on your ability to programmatically pick out the appropriate column; simple example ... one extra column that contains no white space ... `$(NF-1) in f1`; if 3x 'extra' columns (none containing white space): `$(NF-3) in f1`

Answer (score 1):

This is more a side-note, I suggest to use awk, as explained by [markp-fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69305924/171318).

You can use the `join` command:

```
join -11 -23 <(sort -k1,1n file1) <(sort -k3,3n file2)
```

The example above is using `join` with the help of the shell and the sort command:

Command explanation:

```
join
  -11                  # Join based on column 1 of file 1 ...
  -23                  # and column 3 in file 2
  <(sort -k1,1n file1) # sort file 1 based on column 1
  <(sort -k3,3n file2) # sort file 2 based on column 3
```

The `<()` constructs are so called [*process substitutions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), provided by the shell where you run the command in. The output of the command in parentheses will be treated like a file, and can be used as a parameter for our join command. We don't need to create an intermediate, sorted file.